# Using NLTK in C# with pythonnet: Generator object is empty

Tags: c#, python, lambda, nltk, python.net

I'm trying to execute some Python code in C# using Pythonnet. In particular, I'm trying to run some basic NLP operations using the NLTK library, such as get the hyponyms of a given WordNet synset. No matter what I do, the returned generator object in my C# code is always empty.

The code below represents the Python and C# counterparts of what I'm trying to do. Whereas in Python it works flawlessly by returning the hyponyms of a given synset, in C# it does not work, since it does not enter into the foreach loop. Plus, I checked if the generator object is empty with .**next**() and it simply returns it is empty, but not in Python. It looks as if the C# lambda expression was not doing its job.

```
hyponyms = lambda x:x.hyponyms()
synset_example = wn.synset("body_of_water.n.01")
clos = synset_example.closure(hyponyms)       
list = []
        for hyponym in clos:
            for word in hyponym.lemma_names("eng"):
               list.append(word)
```

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
using (Py.GIL())
{
dynamic nltk = Py.Import("nltk.corpus");
dynamic wn = nltk.wordnet;        
Func<dynamic, dynamic> hyponyms = x => x.hyponyms();
dynamic synsetExample = wn.synset("body_of_water.n.01");
dynamic clos = synsetExample.closure(hyponyms);
foreach (dynamic hyponym in clos)
{  
  foreach (dynamic word in hyponym.lemma_names("eng"))
  {
    string hyp = word.ToString();
    list.Add(hyp);
  }

}
```

In Python, it enters into the for loop and .next() function shows the generator object is not empty. In the case of C#, it does not, and checking whether it is empty or not with .**next**(), it returns "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely right that the problem is with the lambda expression not executing properly. Try making it a python lambda instead:

```
dynamic hyponyms = PythonEngine.Eval("lambda x: x.hyponyms()");
```

I didn't delve deep enough to understand why the C# lambda doesn't work. My guess is that pythonnet passes the compiled lambda to python to execute in some way and that way will not know what to do with x.hyponyms().